# Append information like session_id, user_id to every log statement programmatically

Tags: java, logging, logback, rollingfileappender

I am using **logback** for a Java web-service. I have **configured** logback **programmatically**(without using logback.xml). I want to add custom information like **user_id**, **session_id** as part of every log event to the log file.

I am looking for a way to add these extra information from one centralised class(kind of a filter or interceptor), so that, before writing the log to the file, the logger adds these extra info and then writes to the file.

I am using a **RollingFileAppender**. I tried writing a custom RollingFileAppender, but I am not able to figure out the right place to add the custom information before logging to the file. I also have a doubt on whether I have to implement a custom LoggingEvent?

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Add variables to your pattern, and assigne them using MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context), before logging.